# Find the moment generating function of $Y$

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

Let $Y$ denote a random variable with probability density function given by $$f(y) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-|{y}|}, \quad -\infty < y < \infty$$

Find the moment generating function of $Y$.

\begin{align}M_y(t) = E(e^{ty})&=\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{0}e^{-y}e^{ty}dy +\frac12 \int^0_{-\infty}e^{y}e^{ty}dy\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_{0}e^{y(t-1)}dy + \frac12\int^0_{-\infty}e^{y(t+1)}dy \\&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{e^{\infty(t-1)}}{t-1}-\frac{1}{t-1}+\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{e^{-\infty(t+1)}}{t+1}\right)\end{align}

I am currently stuck here. The results will differ according to the value of $t$. I've heard from another source that we  can assume $t<1$. Is the claim valid? Am I missing another step?

Comment: Like  for many mgf, the expression you get will be valid for only a certain range of values of $t$. For the first integral to exist, we need $t\lt 1$. There is a similar condition required for the second integral to exist.

Comment: You clearly have problems with the denominators if $t=\pm 1$ and with the infinite exponentials if $t \gt 1$ or $t \lt -1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $(t-1)>0$, then $e^{\infty(t-1)}=+\infty$ and if $t+1<0$ then $e^{-\infty(t+1)}=+\infty$ and everything goes wrong (i.e. the integrals do not converge). You need to exclude this cases for the integrals to converge. So you must (not can) assume that $t-1<0 \iff t<1$ and $t+1>0 \iff t>-1$. If you combine these two you get that the moment generating function is defined for $|t|<1$.

Comment: So currently I have $\frac{-1}{t^2-1}$ which I can turn into $\frac{1}{1-t^2}$

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Your distribution is the Laplace distribution with parameters $μ=0$ and $b=1$ based on the notation [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution), so you can check by yourself that the MGF is indeed the one you have found!

Comment: Thank You! Very much appreciated! Sometimes one can just forget the basics of calculus that, when faced with questions like this, everything seems to fall apart.....

Comment: Legend! After 7 years, this answer helped me out :D